# R: Squared contingency table

Tags: r, neural-network, predict, contingency

I want to make a contingency table with observations and their predictions based on a neural network. Since I want positives to be on the diagonal, I would like my table to be squared, regardless if there are rows with just 0's. That is, I would like to have

```
   b
a   a b c d e f g
  a 1 0 1 0 2 1 0
  b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  d 2 3 1 2 2 3 2
  e 1 2 1 1 0 1 3
  f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  g 4 2 1 0 3 1 0
```

Instead of:

```
> set.seed(1)
> b<-sample(letters[1:7],40,rep=TRUE)
> a<-sample(letters[1:4],40,rep=TRUE)
> 
> table(a,b)
   b
a   a b c d e f g
  a 1 0 1 0 2 1 0
  d 2 3 1 2 2 3 2
  e 1 2 1 1 0 1 3
  g 4 2 1 0 3 1 0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `a` and `b` to `factor` with `levels` as `union` of both :

```
tmp <- sort(union(a, b))
table(factor(a, levels = tmp), factor(b, levels = tmp))

#    a b c d e f g
#  a 0 1 1 2 2 1 4
#  b 2 1 1 1 2 3 2
#  c 4 0 1 2 0 1 1
#  d 0 1 1 1 3 1 1
#  e 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  g 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```